# Does there exist integer $k >1$ for which $|e^{k\pi}-k\pi-2n|\leq 10^{-6}$

Tags: exponential-function, integers, periodic-functions, transcendental-numbers

It is well known that $e^{k\pi}-k\pi$ is [almost even integer](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html) for $k=1$, now ,are there others $k $ ? Assume if there is some finitly $k$ then what about periodicity of $e$ because we would have something like :$e^{k\pi}\sim 2n+k\pi$? Does there exist integer $k >1$ for which $e^{k\pi}-k\pi$ also almost even integer by means $|e^{k\pi}-k\pi-2n|\leq 10^{-6}$, $n$ is integer  ?

**Note** I meant by periodicity of $e$, Can e represented as period

Comment: What is periodicity of e?

Comment: We know that the periodic solution of trigonometric function are of the form x=kpi+n , now I want to know if e is also periodic solution of some function f satisfying f(x+k pi) =f(x)

Comment: @peter, I meant almost even integer not exactly integer

Comment: @peter An almost integer is a number that is very close to an integer. And for periodicity I meant can e be represented as period ?